# Grouping posts in a category loop by year pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page where I have a big list of books, which are inserted in the loop through a get_posts() query, but since it is too long list, we would like to split it into smaller sections by the year published, and to have two links on top and bottom which would link to the previous/next year group (similar like previous post/next post).

How it is best done? Should I make a separate sub-category for years, and then list it, or set the post-published date and group by that?

What would be the code for any of the solutions, together with the previous/next year link?

My loop is now:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ; ?>

<?php
$myposts = get_posts('posts_per_page=-1&category=3');


if($myposts):
foreach($myposts as $post) :
  setup_postdata($post);
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to me I'll have to solve it by some other method, if it's not possible this way :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you are organizing your books by genres and each genre has its own category, using categories for years would be unwise, since you would have many same categories for each year.

I would suggest using tags for years. And you could separate them very easily by using built in templates.

If you decide to use tags, simple wordpress loop in **tag.php** would do the job

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    //your html output to render the data.
endwhile;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it, I need to output Categories, that are split into sub-section. And in this case I think the previous/next year link won't work.